# Jasper Report Java : Avoid breaking words when wrapping

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Java project that compiles a Jasper XML on the fly and then exports to PDF.

In one of the text field I need JasperReports not to cut the words, and rather to adapt the font size. The font size change works fine, when text is large Jasper reduces the font and wraps the text, but the "do not cut words" part does not work, many times, the PDF will end up with the text over several lines, but the wrapping will cut words in very illogical part, even sometime just leaving one letter of a word on the next line. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have added and tested all the parameters I found in the Jasper documentation and with Google about breaking words, but none, or any combination of them changes the results.

The text field culprit is here:

```xml
<textField textAdjust="ScaleFont" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="10" y="124" width="771"
     height="396" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"
     uuid="bb2d4ab6-fc46-4edd-87ad-18dc4d32d461">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="Boolean.TRUE"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.html.wrap.break.word" value="Boolean.FALSE"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks" value="Boolean.FALSE"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
        <font size="140" isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{letrero}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The Java part that generate the report is here:

```java
try {
    parameters.put(JRJpaQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_JPA_ENTITY_MANAGER, entityManager);
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(Util.getFileInClassPathAsInputStream("/web/report/name-sign.jrxml"));
    
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
    
    return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
} catch (JRException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    logger.error( ex.getMessage());
}
return null;
```

Comment: Shouldn't those properties have `value="true"`/`value="false"` instead of `value="Boolean.TRUE"`/`value="Boolean.FALSE"`?

Comment: also tried like you said, and same result, anyway both should work, this format is used throughout our reports for other parameters in other report and seem to work with this format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Jasper Reports spec :

https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/TextMeasurer.html

Talking about most ot the available parameters for wraping text , and added  the property :

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="false"/>
```

based on what I could understand from the specs this tell jasper not to break at caracters, but only a words... And the issue is solved !

full Text field is now like this :

```
<textField textAdjust="ScaleFont" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="10" y="124" width="771" height="396" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="bb2d4ab6-fc46-4edd-87ad-18dc4d32d461">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="false"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="false"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <font pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="136" isBold="true" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{letrero}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

Hope this will help anyone with a similar issue !

EDIT : This configuration solved the issue in some but not all situations, if the text fits on 2 lines by wrapping one carater of the first word Jasper will still prefer to do that than to slightly reduce the font, but now, at least, if the  one caracter wrapping was occuring on a second or third line the behaviour is now as expected and jasper will rather slighlty reduce font size than wrapping one single digit to a new line... I guess the "ScaleFont" algorithm and the "Truncate" policy are just having having  difficulties working together. So if anyone finds a better solution working always, I am still interested in a better answer than the one I found.

EDIT 2 : Final Solution found, the issue was a font issue, adding : pdfFontName="Helvetica" in the text element works so far. I think that without specifying a font Jasper sets the scaling required based on its default font, and then the if the pdf has the liberty to choose a slightly different font, the scaling defined by Jasper might not give the expected effect. Well just asuming this part...